# Bootstrap navbar hamburger is opening but not closing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

On a phone sized screen, when I click the hamburger once, the navbar opens fine. When I try to close it, nothing happens - it's stuck. Where have I gone wrong? Here's my html:

```
        <header class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#teams-navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="http://{{base_url}}">My Teams</a>
                </div>
                <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="teams-navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'profile_page' user.pk %}">
                                My Profile
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    {% else %}
                    {% block login_button %}{% endblock %}
                    {% endif %}
                </nav>
            </div>
        </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say this is actually an issue with jQuery Toggle. Please ensure jquery is set to toggle "collapsed". One of the ways bootstrap works is by adding/removing classes to buttons/divs/html elements to display them based on css. For example. Pretty Select dropdowns work by adding "open" to a specific div before or after the select button. Hense you can use jQuery to toggle that open when it's clicked. I hope this helps.

```
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#teams-navbar-collapse">

<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("button.navbar-toggle").click(function(){
        $("button.navbar-toggle").toggleClass("collapse");
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can try inside google chrome by right clicking inspect element, then choose the console tab. once there simply past the click function. IE. everything in the .ready(function and replace $ with jQuery. again i hope this helps.

Comment: Aha! I had jQuery installed twice and the toggle was happening twice, messing things up. Thanks for getting me there.

Comment: Glad I was able to help!

Comment: @YPCrumble your comment was the solution for the non closing burger menu. Thanks!